# Duda con Delay y Thread Sleep en Corrutinas

Tags: android, kotlin, corrutinas

Estoy trabajando con corrutinas y ejemplos y me he topado con los métodos delay y Thread.sleep. Por lo que he entendido, con delay suspendemos la ejecución de la corrutina desde donde la lanzamos, hasta que pasa el tiempo y se reanuda por donde fuera, pero si hay más código u otras corrutinas fuera de esta, estan seguirán ejecutandose.

Lo que entiendo con Thread.sleep es que manda a dormir el hilo, pero de aquí no me quedan claras varias cosas... ¿qué hilo es el que duerme? Pongo de ejemplo este código:

```kotlin
private fun sleepAndDelayMethod() {
    // 1. Inicio
    println("¡Go!")

    // 2. Buscar palabras en el background
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        delay(300)
        (1..5).forEach { println("¡Palabra $it encontrada!") }
    }

    // 3. Iniciar temporizador en foreground
    for (i in 10 downTo 1) {
        println("${i}s")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }

    // 4. Tiempo fuera
    println("Se terminó el tiempo")
}
```

En este ejemplo le he pasado como contexto el Default, lo cual tengo entendido que crea otro hilo de ejecución. He probado con IO y obtengo el mismo resultado. Entonces mi duda es, si tengo el for que contiene el Thread.sleep fuera de la corrutina, ¿por qué me está bloqueando toda la ejecución hasta que termina y ya después se ejecuta la corrutina?

Esta es la salida que obtengo:

```bash
3007-3007 I/System.out: ¡Go!
3007-3007 I/System.out: 10s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 9s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 8s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 7s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 6s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 5s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 4s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 3s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 2s
3007-3007 I/System.out: 1s
3007-3007 I/System.out: Se terminó el tiempo
3007-4852 I/System.out: ¡Palabra 1 encontrada!
3007-4852 I/System.out: ¡Palabra 2 encontrada!
3007-4852 I/System.out: ¡Palabra 3 encontrada!
3007-4852 I/System.out: ¡Palabra 4 encontrada!
3007-4852 I/System.out: ¡Palabra 5 encontrada!
```

Comment: Probé el código en mi máquina y ejecuta primero el código dentro de `GlobalScope.launch`. Algunas veces alcanza a imprimirse primero el `10s` lo cual está dentro de lo esperable. Incluso probándolo dentro del Playground de Kotlin da el mismo resultado. Míralo por ti mismo [aquí](https://pl.kotl.in/f1vhuIBdO).

Comment: ¿Y por qué en mi equipo recibo un resultado diferente?

Comment: Ni idea. Aunque sería interesante de averiguar. Alguna configuración diferente debe tener para que pase eso. No se me ocurre exactamente qué podría ser. Yo reiniciaría, instalaría de nuevo el JDK... qué se yo, por ahí debe andar el problema.